# How to use CMake to build a project with C++23 standard library module(import std) with Clang?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++-modules, c++23

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), the Standard Library Modules ([P2465R3](https://wg21.link/P2465R3)) has became an experimental feature in Clang 17 now. But I test it below, it failed:

**CMakeList.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.27)

set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "aa1f7df0-828a-4fcd-9afc-2dc80491aca7")
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

project(1-1)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    FILE_SET all_my_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES
    PUBLIC
    main.cpp
)
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
import std;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello\n";
}
```

It showed:

```bash
fatal error: module 'std' not found
```

So I guess it need to add extra option like `<format>` in Clang 14. But I can't find on llvm doc or google. Could someone give me some help?

I have tried clang's module in a more complex example but `#include` standard library. So I'm sure it's only because of Standard Library Modules.

Comment: I have found the doc in libcxx [doc](https://libcxx.llvm.org/Modules.html), it seems to add   many extra cmake options and two environmental variables. So, we need to wait...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support for standard modules in clang and libc++ is highly experimental. Notably, if you just install it normally, the module files for the `std` module will not be installed.

There are instructions provided by the libc++ team here, if you want to try it out:

https://libcxx.llvm.org/Modules.html